# Distributing different fruit

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I, am having few problems with combinatorics considering distribution of different objects to different subjects.

"How many ways are there to give $3$ kids $3$ bananas, $2$ apples and $3$ pears?"

The tricky part for me is that each kid can but doesn't have to get fruit, meaning that one way to give them is that none of them gets a fruit.

Comment: can a kid get all fruits (3 bananas, 2 apples, and 3 pears)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It is the number of ways to distribute the bananas, times the number of ways to distribute the apples, times the number of ways to distribute the pears.

In principle each is a [**Stars and Bars**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem, and can be solved by general techniques. But for such small numbers it is not really sensible to trot out the heavy machinery.

As a check on your listing, it turns out that there are $10$ ways to distribute the bananas.